# How to determine the type of objects in a collection in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I am attempting to use Reflection in C# to determine at runtime the type of objects in a collection property.  These objects are entities generated by the Entity Framework:

```
Type t = entity.GetType();
PropertyInfo [] propInfo = t.GetProperties();
foreach(PropertyInfo pi in propInfo)
{
    if (pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
    {
        if (pi.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() 
            == typeof(EntityCollection<>))   
        //  'ToString().Contains("EntityCollection"))'  removed d2 TimWi's advice
        //
        //  --->  this is where I need to get the underlying type
        //  --->  of the objects in the collection :-)
        // etc.
    }
}
```

How do I identify the type of objects held by the collection?

EDIT:  updated code above, adding first .IsGenericType query to make it work

Comment: Whats the problem you're trying to solve?  Why do you need to know the types in the collection?  I assume they're not all the same type?

Comment: Actually they are the same type.
I need to create a new object and let the user set its values, but I don't know the type at design time.  So, using reflection, I will get and invoke the constructor, ultimately to add the new object to the appropriate collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GetGenericArguments()` to retrieve the generic arguments of the collection type (for example, for `EntityCollection<string>`, the generic argument is `string`). Since `EntityCollection<>` always has one generic argument, `GetGenericArguments()` will always return a single-element array, so you can safely retrieve the first element of that array:

```
if (pi.PropertyType.IsGeneric &&
    pi.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityCollection<>))
{
    // This is now safe
    var elementType = pi.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

    // ...
}
```

Comment: item[0]?  Do you mean the "GetGenericArguments()"?  That would not be empty.

Comment: Good point Kirk, corrected.
I misunderstood the code to be querying the [0] element of the collection of entity objects (which could have been empty) vs. querying the [0] element of GenericArguments.

Comment: Thanks Timwi.  The only problem is that an exception is thrown if the property isn't a generic type.  I updated my question with your suggestions and the additional "if (pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType)" line.